# Permissions error when trying to view a report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting the below error when attempting to view a report in SSRS 2012.

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\jttest' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
```

I checked the permissions and everything seems fine. At the root folder, I have "Everyone" listed as a browser. The user has explicit browser permissions to the folder the report resides in. The report inherits permissions from the parent and I see the user in the security list when I view the security for the report itself.

I've tried deleting and redeploying the report from Visual Studio. The error is occurring on all browsers on both Macs and PCs. I am at my wit's end.

Comment: To make matters even stranger, there are other reports in this folder that also inherit permissions and I can view those reports without any issues. What is the problem with this one report?

Comment: Are you able to run the report locally?

Comment: The report runs fine as other users. Come to think of it, users that already had browser permissions to the folder before the reports were published are working, but the three new users are the ones giving me problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. This report used a shared dataset and the new users did not have access to the dataset. Giving them access to the dataset fixed the problem and the report now runs for all users.